# How to make a string a function call inside a class?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to call a method inside a class with a given string, here's an example:

```
 class A {
    mymethod(){
      console.log("hey");
    }

    anotherMethod(fName){
      return this.fName();
    }
  }
```

Is this possible in node.js?

Comment: Use bracket notation: `this[fName]()`

Comment: Yep - Solution is already out there as marked by @adiga, also here you can read bit further https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors